# {"line_items":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}

Tags: php, shopify, fulfillment

I am using Shopiy API for fulfill the order in PHP platform. When I try to fulfill the order, I can able to complete and getting a success response fron Shopify. If I pass `line_items` params then I am getting

> {"line_items":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}

Can any one help me to figure out the issue.

```
<?php
require_once("inc/functions.php");
$shop = "my-store";
$fulfilment = array("fulfillment" => array ("tracking_number" =>"123456789",
                                            "tracking_company" => "FedEx",
                                            "line_items"=>array(array("id"=>2143139779))));
$response = shopify_call('accesstoken', $shop, "/admin/orders/1123553027/fulfillments.json", $fulfilment, 'POST');  
print_r($response);
?>
```

Comment: check array(array("id"=>2143139779)))

Comment: You have a syntax error here: `"tracking_number" => 123456789"`, missing an opening `"` before the number.

Comment: Actually, I am having that in my code. By mistaken, I deleted when I format the code in stackoverflow. @duncan

Comment: @hurricane Array format is correct.

Comment: what does the JSON you send to the API look like, compared to the examples given in the documentation: https://docs.shopify.com/api/fulfillment#create

Comment: I have compared the JSON with the document. I found the reason. Need to specify the header content type. Now it fixed. Thanks @duncan

Answer (score 0):

You need a quantity for each line item.

e.g.

```
"line_items" => array(
    array("id" => 12345, "quantity" => 1),
```

Comment: Quantity is a optional parameter.

Comment: I have compared the JSON with the document. I found the reason. Need to specify the header content type. Now it fixed.